# AJAX calendar extender works in both local and host, however styling in host does not render,

Tags: css, asp.net, ajax, iis-7, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an issue that I was hoping someone could help me with - I have searched extensively for an answer but can not find anything.

I am using AJAX calendar extender and it works on both my machine and once published. However it is simply the styling that does not pull through once deployed. I deploy everything via IIS.

This is the css code:

```
.MyCalendar .ajax__calendar_container {
    border:1px solid #646464;
    background-color: #E2E2E4;
    color: black;
    width : 204px;
}


.MyCalendar .ajax__calendar_other .ajax__calendar_day,
.MyCalendar .ajax__calendar_other .ajax__calendar_year {
    color: black;

}
.MyCalendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_day,
.MyCalendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_month,
.MyCalendar .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_year {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
.MyCalendar .ajax__calendar_active .ajax__calendar_day,
.MyCalendar .ajax__calendar_active .ajax__calendar_month,
.MyCalendar .ajax__calendar_active .ajax__calendar_year {
    color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color: black;
}
```

**It appears on host like this:**

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-gjro-AJBjUw/VSPP5gPgPII/AAAAAAAAAP8/_VdhhR-xLaQ/w483-h354-no/HostCalendar.png

**It appears on local like this:**

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-9fio_DBDHEY/VSPQosksr2I/AAAAAAAAAQk/D48MeAOuiFs/w419-h338-no/LocalCalendar.png

Any assistance regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this - for some reason the server does not pick up the css class when it is in the bootstrap.css file , placing the css code in the site.css file solves this